# Registration project error in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm new here and a newbie in coding. I just tried this small project from YT. I copied everything and cannot figure out what is wrong with the error. ('x' is an undeclared prefix.)

Thanks in advance!

```
        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row ="0">
                <Entry Placeholder ="UserName" FontSize ="16" x:Name =" EntryUserName"/>

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Entry Placeholder ="PassWord" IsPassword="true"  FontSize ="16" x:Name =" EntryUserPassword"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
                <Entry Placeholder ="Email" FontSize ="16" x:Name =" EntryUserEmail"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
                <Entry Placeholder ="PhoneNumber" FontSize ="16" x:Name =" EntryUserPhoneNumber"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="4">
                <Button Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="100" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Blue" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` attribute value of your Entry is prefixed with Space,which is not reasonable.

You can replace it with other valid characters.

For example:

replace

```
        <StackLayout Grid.Row ="0">
            <Entry Placeholder ="UserName" FontSize ="16" x:Name =" EntryUserName"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

with:

```
             <StackLayout Grid.Row ="0">
                <Entry Placeholder ="UserName" FontSize ="16" x:Name ="mEntryUserName"   />
            </StackLayout>
```

Other entries are similarly named.

Please refer the following code:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row ="0">
                <Entry Placeholder ="UserName" FontSize ="16" x:Name ="mEntryUserName"   />

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Entry Placeholder ="PassWord" IsPassword="true"  FontSize ="16" x:Name ="mEntryUserPassword"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
                <Entry Placeholder ="Email" FontSize ="16" x:Name ="mEntryUserEmail"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
                <Entry Placeholder ="PhoneNumber" FontSize ="16" x:Name ="mEntryUserPhoneNumber"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="4">
                <Button Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="100" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Blue" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Then in `YourPage.xaml.cs`, you can access your entry in function `Button_Clicked`  as follows:

```
       private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User Name  is : " + mEntryUserName.Text +"<---> PassWord  is = " + mEntryUserPassword.Text);
    }
```